# Issue with "No Staging repository found" in sonatype publish

Tags: scala, sbt, sonatype, sbt-release, sbt-sonatype

I am using the amazing plugin [sbt-ci-release](https://github.com/olafurpg/sbt-ci-release) but I think I am doing something wrong. I posted the [whole details of all my experimentation and steps and attempt as an issue in their repo which can be find here](https://github.com/olafurpg/sbt-ci-release/issues/44).

To do it short, when travis is calling `+publishSigned` it is yelling about

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No staging repository is found. Run publishSigned first
```

When I tried to manually create a staging folder, it succeed without exception but did not deploy any binary and deleted the folder.

I am not sure what to try next.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that my branch tag was `0.1` instead of `v0.1` , adding the heading `v` solve the problem.

See https://github.com/olafurpg/sbt-ci-release/issues/44#issuecomment-503087541